# Convolutional network for data pattern recognition

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, convolution

My convolutional network is designed to classify data patterns. I feed my CNN with 2D matrices to get the relevant class of the pattern if any. There are 4 patterns my classifier recognizes.

**Data:**

Every data sample is a snapshot from a chart of some sequence. The idea is inspired by [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/300351026_Motion_Sequence_Recognition_with_Multi-sensors_Using_Deep_Convolutional_Neural_Network). Data samples are 2-dimensional data-bands, narrow matrices.

**The problem:**

The CNN classifies patterns with high accuracy.
However, there are some patterns that are very similar to one of the 4 classes yet those patterns do not fall under any class.

There are options to use fine-grain models or raise the threshold to the highest possible value. However, those options don't improve the model's accuracy significantly. Similar patterns are still largely classified as valid. I augmented data by expanding the matrices with more data, which didn't work well as well. A naked eye can see the difference between similar patterns and valid patterns. It seems that the CNN can't see subtle differences that are obvious to the human eye.

What would you recommend trying to make the model see those differences?

Thanks!
These are last layers. The rest part consists of conv and poooling layers

```
model.add(Dense(output_classes,
                kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization),
                kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                bias_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regularization)))

model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,
                       beta_1=0.9,
                       beta_2=0.999,
                       epsilon=1e-08,
                       decay=0.0)

print('Compiling the model...')

model.compile(optimizer=adam, 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Comment: Do you mean there are more than 4 patterns? Create 5 classes, one of them being "other".

Comment: I need the network to classify 4 patterns only. There are lots of other patterns that are not relevant to the task. If I create the 5th class I need to train the network with the relevant data. The 5th class doesn't solve the problem of similarity. The model will ignore the 5th class as a pattern can be very similar to one of 1-4 classes. I have already tried this approach.

Comment: Don't you need the network to classify 4 patterns **and** identify patterns that aren't any of the four?

Comment: yes, precisely. I need the network to produce 1 to 4 result if the sample falls under one of the classes or 0 if it can't be recognized according to the 4 classes.

Comment: Why not 1 to 5, being 5 an undesired pattern?

Comment: well as I said above, I tried this approach as well and it didn't work well. I can collect similar patterns and train a new class. But the model can't see the difference and the accuracy falls. Eventually, the model has 2 classes that to the model are the same.

Comment: Are you using `Conv1D` or `Conv2D`?

Comment: I tried both. With Conv2D I get slightly better accuracy.

Comment: I have also created a new class for each to reflect similar sample to the core 4 classes. When the model has 8 classes the accuracy falls to 40%, and the model can't classify at all. It produces 0 result.

Comment: Are you using 'softmax' or 'categorical_crossentropy'? Could you add your relevant part of the code?

Comment: These two will never give you zero values. You should change to `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` for instance.

Comment: added, please see the first post.

Comment: I will try with sigmoid and get back with the result. Thank you.

Comment: binary_crossentropy should not be applied in a multiclass classification problem, should it?

Comment: It seems to work, I never had problems with that. As long as you're using `sigmoid` as the final activation. You can try others too, 'mse', 'mae', etc. But 'softmax' cannot result in 0 for all classes.

Comment: what if I use 0.9 threshold with softmax? Will it not produce 0 results again?

Comment: What is 0.9 threshold? I don't know that. But 'softmax' is designed so that all classes always sum 1. It's simply not designed to produce zeros.

Comment: Let me put this way. I have 4 classes and the model sums 1 for all classes for a given pattern. What if I set to pick the class that has the probability value above 0.9? Actually, I use this approach and this doesn't work well as well. Similar samples have probabilities above 0.9. So this is again due to the fact that the model can't see the differences.

Comment: Forget the `softmax`. It will always make a "balance" between the 4. If the model is certain that 3 classes are wrong, it will always put everything at the 4th class. Always. There isn't possibility to do any different. (If you're using 5 classes, then there is this possibility).

Comment: I did a quick network train and test. softmax and binary_crossentropy don't make a significant change. It means that the problem is with either the data or the model.

Comment: I trained the model with 8 classes and got some improvement. Despite I adjusted the class weights for the 8 classes the network is biased to the similar group of samples.

Comment: For example, the recent tests showed the following results: there are 30% true positive results for Class 1 and 20% of Class 1 results are identified in a dataset of Class 5 (similar to Class 1). Before switching to sigmoid the results were correlated, 70% of true positives in Class 1 (30% identified as Class 5) and 30% of true positives in Class 5, the rest samples in the dataset of Class 5 (70%) were identified as Class 1. I will provide further updates if there is more improvement.

Comment: Can you give us an update - what has happened during the latest year? What did you do to optimize the result/model?

Comment: I slightly redesigned the input, did a bit of data augmentation and the result was much better. We want the machine to see what we humans can see with our sophisticated mind but the machine can see data in a primitive way only. I found out that in order to achieve higher accuracy rates it is crucial to simplify data and make it understandable for the machine. For example, the machine perfectly understands 2 stages: light (1) and darkness(0). Only then the machine can recognize subtle differences.